# Problem with converting map to priority queue

Tags: c++, dictionary, priority-queue, std-pair

Help me please, why it is not work?

I want to convert map<int, int> to priority queue of pairs, which which will be sorted by the second argument.

```
auto cmp = [](pair<int, int>& p1, pair<int, int>& p2) {return p1.second > p2.second;};

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(cmp)> q;

map<int, int> m{{1,1}, {2,3}, {4,100}};

for (auto a : m)
    q_.push(a);
```

i want to get such a pq in descending order of priority {{4,100}, {2,3}, {1,1}}.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show?`Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve].

Comment: Please explain what 'it doesn't work' means. What error or problem do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
```

Lambda functions don't have default constructors (at least in some versions of C++) the true situation seems to be complicated. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda